# dynamically changing text in textblock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am trying to make an windows phone application....
in this app I have to display a page with a text block and a next and previous button and the text in textblock changes accordingly.....text is not much for a single page its like 3 to 4 lines per page and around a 1000 pages 
so what I thought was that I could save the text in database with serial numbers and retrieve it even with the serial number....but as I see no database support for windows phone...maybe am wrong....also I don't want to use any third party api that is not provided by Microsoft itself
so please someone guide me 
greatly appreciate any help
hope m clear....

Comment: why not save them in a dictionary? agree with Zdravko. Check this out : [isolated storage](http://www.david-amador.com/2010/10/using-isolatedstorage-to-saveload-files-on-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: I don't know about dictionary I will look it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for local databases on windows phone but none of them comes from Microsoft. For 1000 lines I would use an xml file stored in the isolated storage or even a plain text file.

Comment: actually it is 4x1000 lines
that is 3 or 4 lines for approx. thousand pages maybe more not sure...and I intend to increase that size as I update the app in long run....also wont loading that xml file take time because I just may not need all the pages it maybe just one also...

Comment: still, quite insignificant... if you do something like a LINQ query against it it will feed instantaneous...

Comment: will this work for me?
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2011/10/01/LINQ-to-SQL-on-Windows-Phone-75.aspx?Page=1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546200.aspx

Comment: Linq-to-sql would work if you are targeting 7.5 (mango) or newer but you still need some way to ship your data (i.e. xml file) and then you wouldn't really gain anything compared to just querying that xml file...

Comment: look here how to copy file to isolated storage: http://technodave.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/moving-files-from-xap-to-isolated-storage-for-local-html-content-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: look here how to use linq-to-xml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which version you are developing on. On windows phone 7.0, <strike>7.1</strike> database is not supported, you could use IsolatedStorage to store in Folder/file format as suggested by Zdarvko.

For Windows 7.5-mango,(7.1 too - link given by Paras - http://debugmode.net/2011/09/25/local-database-application-for-windows-phone/), Paras has already provided with links.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone does support Local DB.

Look here for sample code and examples:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-mapping-and-database-operations
http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-SQL-CE--Linq-to-SQL
http://debugmode.net/2011/09/25/local-database-application-for-windows-phone/

You can also use Isolated Storage for your purpose:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage